# Echo autoincrement id doubt

Tags: php, mysql, echo, auto-increment

can I print the id, even if it's autoincrement ? Because the way I'm doing I'm using an empty variable for id.

```
$id= "";

mysql_connect(localhost,$username,$password);

@mysql_select_db($database) or die ("Não conectou com a base $database");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1(id,...)
VALUES ('".$id."',....)")
or die(mysql_error());

mysql_close();

echo "Your id is :";

echo "".$id;
```

I'm trying to print the id, but it's coming blank. I checked the table and there's an id number there. How can I print it then at?

Thanks for the attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the last auto-generated id on a connection with [mysql_insert_id()](http://uk.php.net/mysql_insert_id)

Your sample should look like this:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO table1(...) VALUES (....)")
   or die(mysql_error());

$id=mysql_insert_id();

echo "Your id is : $id";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "Blah Blah Blah". mysql_insert_id() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

First insert a $id into database as 0.
Here I am using $id = count and $field will print value

> $dbconn =
>   mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass) or
>   die (mysql_error()); // try to connect
>   to database
>     mysql_select_db($db,$dbconn);
>     mysql_query("INSERT INTO counter
>   (`count`) VALUES (\'0\')");
>     mysql_close($dbconn);

Then update it

> $field)       {       echo $field;  ?>

This will may help you...

Comment: I'm leaving it blank because another id will be generated in the database, because i checked the option autoincrement. I want to know how do I get the new generated autoincremented id from the table of the database and print it, because my $.id, is still blank.

Thanks for the attention